# Is it possible to use my domain for the URL for publicly available objects in a Google Cloud Storage Bucket?

Tags: redirect, dns, google-cloud-storage

I set up a Google Cloud Storage bucket with a domain I own, after going through the ownership verification step.

I was thinking I would be able to use the named bucket to provide links under my own domain. I can't really explain this clearly, so bear with me please. I'll give an example.

I uploaded a file with name `test`. After making it publicly available, I can get a URL so anybody can access the file. The URL looks like this:

`https://storage.googleapis.com/media.example.com/test`

What I thought I'd be able to do is have it generate a link that looks like this:

`https://media.example.com/test`

Is this possible at all? I realize I can set something up so requests to `https://media.example.com/test` redirect to `https://storage.googleapis.com/media.example.com/test`, but that's kind of messy, among other things.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by creating a CNAME record in the domain configuration for your domain.

Simply add a CNAME record for `media.example.com` with `c.storage.googleapis.com` as the canonical name and the redirection happens automagically.

There's an entire page dedicated to doing exactly this in the GCP docs here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website

Comment: Oh wow, that is cool. I didn't think that would work, since `media.example.com/test` would simply redirect to `c.storage.googleapis.com/test` right? Do they have it set up like virtual hosts to detect the URL entered?

Comment: Basically URLs and the domain names are completely different things. Everything before the slash in the URI is the hostname and eventually resolved to an IP address. This is all handled by DNS. When you add the CNAME record you are changing the IP address to which the domain resolves. Now the client will ask the new IP address for the /test endpoint which now points to GCP. GCP must be setup to listen to the different hostname as well but this is all handled internally (Google the HTTP Host header).

Comment: I don't think CNAME records have anything to do with IP addresses... but yeah that's what I was surprised by, it knowing which bucket to serve based on the original requested url. What I mean is `c.storage.googleapis.com` doesn't resolve to `storage.googleapis.com/media.example.com`

Comment: Well the CNAME indirectly resolves to an IP address via a domain name, whereas for example A records resolve to an IP directly. Im not sure exactly how the GCP thing works internally, probably some fancy redirection...